# How to use constant in the ON condition in Yii2 hasMany relation

Tags: yii2, has-many, polymorphic-associations, relation

I try to create a polymorphic association, what is common in Rails but unfortunately not in Yii2. As part of the implementation I need to define the relation:

```php
public function getImages()
{
   return $this->hasMany(RecipeImage::className(), 
       ['imageable_id' => 'id', 'imageable_type' => 'Person']);
}
```

But this doesn't work, because 'Person' is treated as an attribute of the current model, but it is a constant (class name for the polymorphic association).

If I try to use 'andWhere' it adds the condition of course in a WHERE clause instead of the ON clause, causing that only records with existing image returned.

```php
public function getImages()
{
   return $this->hasMany(RecipeImage::className(), ['imageable_id' => 'id'])->
       andWhere(['imageable_type' => 'Ingredient']);
}
```

How can I define the relation? There is no andOn method.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In this case you can modify ON condition with `andOnCondition` method:

```
public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RecipeImage::className(), ['imageable_id' => 'id'])
        ->andOnCondition(['imageable_type' => 'Person']);
}
```

**Official docs:**

- [andOnCondition:](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#andOnCondition%28%29-detail)