# Yii2 has many or where

Tags: yii2, many-to-many

Hello i have question about Yii2 has many.

My table structure :

```
-------------------------
----col1------col2-------

------3---------4--------

------4---------1--------
```

and now i have method in my Model class:

```
getCols(){
   return $this->hasMany(Cols::className,['col1'=>'id']);
}
```

and now i want to get all records where for example col1 = 4 or col2 = 4, so how can i set or statement ? I know that i can do

```
getCols(){
   return $this->hasMany(Cols::className,['col1'=>'id','col2'=>'id']);
}
```

but this method returns me records for example where col1 = 4 AND col2 = 4

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly.

```
getCols(){
   return $this->hasMany(Cols::className(), ['col1' => 'id'])
    ->orOnCondition(['col2' => 'id']);  
}
```

*Please confirm in the comment if it works.*

> REF1 : [How to use constant in the ON condition in Yii2 hasMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503341/how-to-use-constant-in-the-on-condition-in-yii2-hasmany-relation)
>
> REF2 : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#orOnCondition()-detail

Comment: i update the answer can you check this approach works?